# Too long time taken by Mysql function

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'item' with approximately 8500 rows and another table named 'stock' which stores stock of items date-wise and location-wise (I have 2 locations of stock).

The Stock table structure is given below:

```
stock_dt date           - Stores the Date of Stock,
loc_id varchar(3)       - Stores the Location of Stock,
item_id varchar(6)      - Stores the Item Code,
item_qty decimal(20,2)  - Stores the Item Stock Quantity,
item_cost decimal(20,2) - Stores the Item Stock Cost Value
```

Whenever there is movement of any Item from-or-to Stores, a row is inserted into the Stock table with the updated Stock Figures for the specific item. Currently the Stock table contains about 125,000 rows.

Now I have one function that takes two date parameters (adt_from and adt_to), and retrieves Stock of each item at each location on both dates i.e. Opening and Closing Stock of Items at each location and does some other computations with the Stocks...

Below is the section of the function that is taking unusually long time (almost 15 minutes).

"
    -- Variable declarations

```
declare cur_item cursor for
select item_id
from   item
order by item_id;

declare cur_loc cursor for
select loc_id
from   location;

declare continue handler for not found set not_found = true;

set not_found = false;

open cur_item;

fetch cur_item into s_item;

read_item:
loop
    if not_found then
        leave read_item;
    end if;

    set d_opng_qty = 0;
    set d_opng_cost = 0;
    set d_cls_qty = 0;
    set d_cls_cost = 0;

    open cur_loc;

    fetch cur_loc into s_loc;

    read_loc:
    loop
        if not_found then
            leave read_loc;
        end if;

        -- For Opening Stock:
        select item_qty,
               item_cost
        into   d_opng_qty,
               d_opng_cost
        from   stock
        where  stock_dt < adt_from
        and    loc_id = s_loc
        and    item_id = s_item
        order by stock_dt desc
        limit 1;

        -- For Closing Stock:
        select item_qty,
               item_cost
        into   d_cls_qty,
               d_cls_cost
        from   stock
        where  stock_dt <= adt_to
        and    loc_id = s_loc
        and    item_id = s_item
        order by stock_dt desc
        limit 1;

        fetch cur_loc into s_loc;
    end loop;

    fetch cur_item into s_item;      
end loop;
```

"

Stock table is indexed on stock_dt, loc_id and item_id.

I have tried enabling query_cache and set query_cache_size to 128M but there seems to be no improvement at all.

I commented the 2 queries on Stock and the program just finishes the rest of the execution in just few seconds. Any suggestion?

Comment: Wouldn't a group by be more appropriate here than a manual loop? I haven't looked in detail at what you're doing so I might be wrong. You could always try running those statements in isolation and with EXPLAIN to see what the query planner is doing with them. Also remember that indexing multiple columns individually won't help (much) here; you need a multi-column index to get the full benefit (maybe item, location, date would be the best order)

Comment: It is already a composite index on stock_dt, loc_id and item_id

Comment: It was the Indexing Order indeed.... Now I changed the composite index to the order of item, location, date and that drastically changed the response time. The function now takes just a few seconds. Thanks Dave... Thanks to all others as well for your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I guess that here the problem is caused by those ORDER BY.

Assuming you have a composite index on (item, location, date), I think you need

```
ORDER BY item desc, location desc, date desc
```

in order for the search to start at the correct end and to return after 1 hit.

The reason is that even though it will be hitting the composite index (item, location, date) for one item, it will traverse the index in the direction of the most significant column (implicit ORDER BY item ASC, location ASC). It will hence need to scan the whole of the item's partial history to obtain the most recent record.

I would try commenting out the ORDER BY and see if this is what causing the problem.

Comment: Since the OP has where item=? AND location=? in the statements this should not be a problem for the query planner. I think much more likely is that there is no composite index, but really we need to see the result of an EXPLAIN to say for sure.

Comment: @Dave I edited my answer to explain it a bit better, but I agree - difficult to say at this stage.

Comment: @Dave - Please be informed that it is a composite key on stock_dt, loc_id and item_id